# Apache flume does not run hadoop 3.1.0 Flume 1.11

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hdfs, flume

I configured my flume application to perform searches on Twitter but it has been stuck on that part for a long time and it won't go away, I've tried starting again several times

I was hoping it would start reading Twitter files and send them to my HDFs but it won't

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.